# Как передать клик с текста на кнопку?

Tags: javascript

Как при клике на "Поделиться" вызывать клик на кнопке share?

```css
.ya-share2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
}

.ya-share2__link_more {
  background: none !important;
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .ya-share2 {
    top: -4px;
    left: -3px;
  }
}

.button {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-left: 23px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #262b33;
  text-decoration: underline;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js'></script>
<span class="button">
  <span class="ya-share2" data-curtain data-shape="round" data-limit="0" data-more-button-type="short" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,telegram,twitter,viber,whatsapp"></span> Поделиться
</span>
```

Comment: уточните пожалуйста что нужно произойти после клика на слово?

Comment: @Мнебезсахара должно просиходить то же самое, что происходит при клике на иконку

Comment: на jQuery могу сказать как

Comment: @Мнебезсахара главное чтоб работало

Comment: обновил ответ. если что дай знать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
setTimeout(()=>{ // Имитация готовности DOM

  let button = document.querySelector('.button');
  
  button.addEventListener( 'click', e => {
    if( e.target !== button ) return;
    e.stopPropagation();
    button.querySelector('.ya-share2__item_more').click();
  })
  
}, 1000 );
```

```css
.ya-share2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
}

.ya-share2__link_more {
  background: none !important;
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .ya-share2 {
    top: -4px;
    left: -3px;
  }
}

.button {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-left: 23px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #262b33;
  text-decoration: underline;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js'></script>
<span class="button">
  <span class="ya-share2" data-curtain data-shape="round" data-limit="0" data-more-button-type="short" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,telegram,twitter,viber,whatsapp"></span> Поделиться
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это на jQuery. Вместо `#target` пишите класс вашего "Поделится"

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  $('.button').trigger('click');;
});
```